# Where does JBoss-AS 7.1 store https error messages?

Tags: https, jboss7.x

I'm trying to configure https on JBoss-AS 7.1.  When I connect via https I get a blank screen.  The JBoss management console shows 4 errors on 4 requests for the https connector, but there is nothing the standalone/log/server.log for any of these failed requests.

Where is JBoss logging the failed https?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try setting the log level to DEBUG in the standalone.xml and then look at the server.log
you may find [this link](https://community.jboss.org/message/642556) useful